# visual studio code how to run to show the output only

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I just download visual studio code to do my college project in C language. I already download all the necessary extensions to run the code but when I want to run the code option only the terminal will send me this

> PS C:\Users\User\Documents\c test> cd "c:\Users\User\Documents\c test" ; if ($?) { g++ Hello world.c -o Hello world } ; if ($?) { .\Hello world }
> cc1plus.exe: fatal error: world.c: No such file or directory
> compilation terminated.

but if I run it in debug C\C++ file or Run C\C++ file the code output will show can you help me to make the terminal will show the output only

Comment: You seem to have a space in your file name. You need to make sure that your json file for building and running the code encloses it in quotes. Or you could just not use spaces in file names.

Comment: thank for replying. I already did like what you instructed thanks for that I don't get any errors but apparently, I still can't get any output at output

Comment: As you do not show any code, no one can tell you what you did wrong. Open another question and include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you have problems with your code.